# Is it possible to add a user-filtered button in Django

Tags: python, django, navigation

I have a Base.html template that extends to the rest of my HTML pages in my app, In this base.html file, it has a nav-bar that has a bunch of < a > tags that link to the different pages.

Is it possible to limit the visibility of this < a > tag based on a user's name or users role on the database or would I need to add this in the function of rendering the page to which the < a > tag loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
{% if user.username == 'KyleStranger' %}
    your button here
{% endif %}
```

or

`{% if user.is_staff %}` or

`{% if perms.app_label.permission_name %}` -> example: `perms.myapp.can_edit_post`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **User** model in your html file and then use a if condition to check that:

```py
{% if request.user.id == user.id %}
        Yep!
{% endif %}
```